# learning python multipe plots on the same set of axis

Tags: python, plot

How would I setup this plot up in Python?

Here is what I do in Mathematica:

```
mykvalue = Table[k, {k, 0, 10, 1}];

u[r_, k_] = 1/(2*r^2) + k/(2*r^2);

Plot[u[r, mykvalue], {r, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: take a look at matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my opinion one of the simplest way to do it would be to use a multidimensional list to store the values and than plot using matplotlib. this is what i mean

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = range(11)

yvals = [[] for i in range(len(k))] #there should be a more pythonic way to
x = np.arange(0.4,5,0.1)               #create nested lists i think, ALM I added np.


for i in k:
    for j in x:
        i = float(i) #this conversion from int to float was to debug,       
        j = float(j) #it should be made better
        y=1/(2*j**2) + i/(2*j**2)
        i = int(i)
        yvals[i].append(y)


for i in k:
    plt.plot(x,yvals[i])

plt.show()
```

that should work i guess. you can fiddle around with matplotlib to fix the axes and get labels and stuff.

Comment: thanks.  I will working on understanding the code.  Is there a way to have k range from -10 to 10 to see negative values?

Answer (score 0):

From the Matplotlib gallery - and they show the source code.

This is close:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_limits.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html

http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

HTH